# Add an assembly reference under the hood in .net projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, assemblies

After a repeated search it seems I could not manage to find a true answer to this question.

What happened when we add an assembly reference to our .net projects in visual studio, and does it defers when we work with ASP.net mvc, web api projects or win forms, wpf projects or any other type of projects in visual studio?

Comment: Assembly reference information is saved in project files. What are you looking for is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML element is added into your project when you add some reference. Project structure is described by [MSBuild format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx#BKMK_ProjectFile). Type of added XML element dependence on the used reference. `<ProjectReference>` added if you add Project reference. It looks like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SomeProject\SomeProject.csproj">
    <Project>{6CA7AB2C-2D8D-422A-9FD4-2992BE62720A}</Project>
    <Name>SomeProject</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

`<Reference>` element added if you add managed library reference. It looks like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="SomeProject">
    <HintPath>..\Libraries\SomeProject.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

If you are interested in creating projects from scratch "[Creating an MSBuild Project File from Scratch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx)" article will be useful.

Comment: pretty good explanation to me, therefor its the responsibility of MSBuild to provide c# compiler (in smart way) the necessary switches to compile the project files

Answer (score 0):

You don't find anything because the answer is really simple.

> What happened when we add an assembly reference to our .net projects in visual studio,

The Reference makes the Namespaces and Types contained in that Assembly available to our local project.

> and does it defers when we work with ASP.net mvc, web api projects or win forms, wpf projects or any other type of projects in visual studio?

No.  To .Net, a References is a Reference.  The exact sub-stack doesn't matter because it's still all .Net.  The Reference might be visualized differently, but that's just UI.